# Probability $P(A \cap B)$ vs $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$

Tags: probability

### Problem

Let $P(A) = 0,4$ , $P(B) = 0.6$, $P(A \cup B) = 0.86$.

Now solve $P(A \cap B)$

### Attempt to solve

I know that when $A$ and $B$ are independent events, then

$$ P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B) = 0.4 \cdot 0.6 = 0.24. $$

I also know that if $A$ and $B$ are independent then

$$ P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B). $$

Now I could use the previous equality to solve for $P(A \cap B)$ which results in

$$ P(A \cap B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B) = 0.4 + 0.6 - 0.86 = 0.14 $$

Now I don't really understand why I have two different results?

Comment: The formula $\Pr(A \cup B) = \Pr(A) + \Pr(B) - \Pr(A \cap B)$ is true in general.  The formula $\Pr(A \cap B) = \Pr(A)\Pr(B)$ holds for independent events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first method only works if $A$, $B$ are independent. The second method (Inclusion-Exclusion principle) works in general. Since we don't know whether $A$, $B$ are independent we should use the second method.

Comment: To add to that, the above computation proves that $A,B$ are in fact dependent.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I don't really understand why I have two different results?

The first method requires the events to be independent.

The second method *always* holds.

Since the methods give different answers, this shows that these events are **not** independent.

Therefore the second result is the correct answer.